# Manifest settings not supporting CM9

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I have a couple of applications on the market. Today I have updated my phone to CM9 and have just noticed that my apps are not compatible with this software.

What i would like to work out is what permissions in the manifest could prevent this from showing up in the market?

Would it be related to the target version?

I don't think screen resolutions would be the issue because the resolution has not changed and I know for a fact that people have had the apps working on tablet devices with much larger displays.

Comment: What uses-feature and uses-permission you defined in those apps that CM9 doesn't like for example?

Comment: AFAIK, modded ROMs can't legitimately have Google Play, unless they added in some "back up the APK from the device and restore it after modding" trick that I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue, as well. All of my apps are viewable on the Google Play Store, but none of my live wallpapers are viewable. I think it has to do with the `<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />` element. CM9 might not have this set properly because I can see an app that doesn't have this line in the manifest and can't see apps with this line. Do you see the same thing?

Comment: Thing I can't properly test (because I don't know how) is how to modify uses-feature elements in CM9. My device is the pyramid, btw.